# curve fitting optimisation scipy python numpy

Tags: python, scipy

This post builds on my previous question

I have some X data and some Y data, the Y data can be fit as a weighted sum of the X data, and my problem is to find the coefficients that give the best fit.

I now understand one way to do that, though I realise it may not be the best or optimal way.

However, the X-data that I have may sometimes be shifted, such that the best fit is only obtained after shifting or sliding each of the columns of X up or down by N increments.

I have tried to see if np.roll could be used to do this but I am stuck because my function now needs both the coefficents and the integer values for np.roll that can be used to shift columns up or down by N to improve the fit.

I think my main issue is that don't understand how I can pass these two different kinds of parameters to curvefit - is it possible?

Perhaps np.roll is not the best way to do this? so any suggestions for another way would also be appreciated.

In my example below, shifting the second column by -1 would produce a better fit of the Xdata to the Ydata.

```
xdata = np.array([[1.0, 1.0],[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 2.0], [2.0, 1.0],[1.0, 1.0]])

ydata = np.array([3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 9.0, 5.0, 3.0])


def fitfunc(xdata, *params):
    ctx = 0.0

    # y is not yet defined by somehow I would like it to take the values passed in the second np.array defined in c below
    # the for loop should just run twice in this example

    for n in range(len(params)): 
        ctx = params[n]*np.roll(xdata[:,n], y, axis=0) + ctx  
    return ctx, y

#initial guesses for fitting parameters
c = (np.array([0.6, 0.3]), np.array([1, 1])) # the second np.array is what I would like to pass a y's 

# fit data using SciPy's Levenberg-Marquart method
nlfit, nlpcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fitfunc, xdata, ydata, p0=(c), sigma=None)

print (nlfit)
```

thank you an advance for any help

Comment: Are you trying to use a linear model of the form y = mx + b, and you want to include the constant term b, which shifts the line up and down? Or is your data a set of time series, where you're not sure what lags of the x-variables to use (maybe implied by np.roll)?

Comment: My data are spectra. so the Xdata array might be a matrix of two spectra arranged in columns.  From my previous question on this topic I believe my Xdata can describe my ydata as X*a + X*b...etc = Ydata.  The reason I want to also to shift my x data columns up and down when trying to optimise the fit is that experimental errors mean that such shifts are common in real data, so as well as mutiplying each column of Xdata by a coefficient, I'm hopefully there is some way to trial shifts of the Xdata columns relative to one another to find the best fit.

Comment: I hope that clarifies what I hope to achieve? np.roll is just one way I thought I might be able to achieve this shifting of columns relative to one another.  The spectra involved have thousands of points so my thinking was that rolling a few points from one end to the other or vice versa to get a better fit might be a way to achieve this.

Comment: Ah ok. You can pass other parameters by making a longer parameter array, then adjusting fitfunc so that you separate out the 'slope' parameters and the 'shift' parameters. As you note, the shift parameters must be integers, which curve_fit doesn't do. Ultimately, starting from scratch here seems like the wrong way to go about this. I'm guessing there are known ways to do this kind of analysis, with associated libraries, and I think it's probably best to ask at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) about the kind of analysis you're trying to perform to get pointers.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll post a question to the site you suggest.  In the meantime if you or anyone else could provide any pointers about how to separate out parameters passed to curve I would be interested to learn how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curve_fit` expects a single array of parameters, which you can use however you want in `fitfunc`. In this example, we have p columns, and each column we have a slope and a shift, so in the end we need a parameter array of 2*p elements. The initial parameter array needs to look like this:

```
c = np.array([0.6, 0.3, 1, 1])
```

Inside `fitfunc`, I split the parameter array into:

- `slope_params`, an array of slope parameters, using `params[:cols]`, which takes the first p elements, and
- `shift_params`, an array of shift parameters, using `params[cols:]`, which takes the last p elements.

Full code for `fitfunc`:

```
def fitfunc(xdata, *params):
    # Get number of columns in data
    cols = xdata.shape[1]

    # Get slope parameters
    slope_params = params[:cols]

    # Get shift parameters and convert to int
    shift_params = [int(round(n)) for n in params[cols:]]

    # Calculate fit
    ctx = 0.0
    for n in range(len(slope_params)):
        ctx = slope_params[n] * np.roll(xdata[:,n], shift_params[n], axis=0) + ctx

    # Show progress
    print(params)

    return ctx
```

Note that we have to convert the shift parameters to integers, using `[int(round(n)) for n in params[cols:]]`.

Using this with `curve_fit` doesn't change the shift parameters at all and gives a warning:

```
(0.59999999999999998, 0.29999999999999999, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.59999999999999998, 0.29999999999999999, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.59999999999999998, 0.29999999999999999, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.60000000894069672, 0.29999999999999999, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.59999999999999998, 0.30000000447034836, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.59999999999999998, 0.29999999999999999, 1.0000000149011612, 1.0)
(0.59999999999999998, 0.29999999999999999, 1.0, 1.0000000149011612)
(-0.40816307558733345, 3.6326528012731845, 1.0, 1.0)
(-0.40816306950522968, 3.6326528012731845, 1.0, 1.0)
(-0.40816307558733345, 3.6326528554039292, 1.0, 1.0)
(-0.40816307558733345, 3.6326528012731845, 1.0000000149011612, 1.0)
(-0.40816307558733345, 3.6326528012731845, 1.0, 1.0000000149011612)
(-0.40816327556523363, 3.632653071646589, 1.0, 1.0)
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)
[-0.40816328  3.63265307  1.          1.        ]
```

You might be able to adjust the optimization settings to get better results, but I don't think this is the most promising approach for your problem.

Comment: thanks for explaining how to this its most useful to see the mechanics and will no doubt be useful to others, even if you think in my case it will not be a way to solve the original problem